# Databricks: Automatically run notebook on databricks cluster launch

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Is there anyway to automatically trigger a notebook to be executed once a cluster starts?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: hello, thanks shane and alex for your help.

for context I am trying to concatenate config parameters on launch, parameters which include azure secret keys. similar query here: https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y000097eETcSAM/how-do-we-concatenate-some-fixed-string-with-a-secret-value-in-spark-config-in-databricks-job-cluster

my idea was to do this in a notebook and trigger this notebook to concatenate and set the config params before other notebooks are used.

thanks again.

Comment: why not set config parameters in the cluster settings? It would be even more secure as you can refer secrets directly, without exposing them to notebooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using jobs cluster and dynamically attach your notebooks, which will trigger the notebook once the cluster comes up.
https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html#create-a-job

[image]

If you see the above pic, you could attach your notebook and choose the type as 'notebook' and when ever the cluster comes up, it will automatically deploy your notebook and start its execution.

Comment: In my experience, jobs are not triggered upon starting the cluster. Is this a setting somewhere?